# SQL :Varchar invalid for Sum operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use this code trying to get sum of 4,202 & 203 but it return me error

```
SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT id,fieldNumber,fieldData FROM iso_fields) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
 SUM(fieldData) 
FOR fieldNumber IN ([4],[202],[203])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Error :

```
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.
```

Reason:

```
Table using varchar instead of int
```

What can i do about it? There is no way to alter the table back.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column? Don't do that.

Comment: technically its storing a hex number

Comment: That's not a good reason. Store it as an `integer` column and convert it to hex when _displaying_ it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datatype of `fieldData` is `varchar` so the error. If `fieldData` column does not have any `varchar` data then you can do an *explicit* conversion to `INT` in `pivot` source query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT id,fieldNumber, fieldData FROM iso_fields) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
 MAX(fieldData) 
FOR fieldNumber IN ([4],[202],[203])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Seems like my column have a varchar data. solution?

Comment: @user3165474 - Just use `MAX` aggregate in case there are no duplicates for `id,fieldNumber & fieldData` combination. Updated my answer

Comment: I get what u mean. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that all fieldData values are numeric, you can use `cast` or `convert` :

```
SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT id,fieldNumber,fieldData FROM iso_fields) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(cast(fieldData as int)) 
FOR fieldNumber IN ([4],[202],[203])
) AS PivotTable;
```

But if not ensure about numeric values in fieldData, you can use `try_cast` or `try_convert` (SQL Server 2012 and above):

```
SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT id,fieldNumber,fieldData FROM iso_fields) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(try_cast(fieldData as int))
FOR fieldNumber IN ([4],[202],[203])
) AS PivotTable;
```